# Amelia II: Headers and row numbers

Tags: r, machine-learning, missing-data, forecasting

I am using Amelia II to impute (guess) missing data. The problem is that when I generate a CSV file with the results, it comes with a header and each row starts now with a row number. Is there a way to avoid both the header and the row numbers?

The code I am using looks like this:

```
d = read.csv(input_filename, header=FALSE);
a = amelia(d, m = 5);
write.amelia(obj = a, file.stem=output_filename_stem);
```

EDIT: I tried to replace the last line by

```
write.amelia(obj = a, file.stem=output_filename_stem, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE);
```

The results: row.names = FALSE worked fine but I got an "attempt to set 'col.names' ignored" error message when I tried to set col.names = FALSE.

Comment: I tried it and format = "table" worked but now values are separated by a space instead of a comma. Is it possible to have them separated by a comma?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this from remaining unanswered forever, here's the comments converted to an answer..

If you use `write.table` to generate your data, just add the arguments `row.names = FALSE` and `col.names = FALSE` to generate the file without header and row names. The same seems to apply for `write.amelia`, but you should then specify `format = "table"` and `sep = ","`. So for your example, it would be:

```
write.amelia(obj = a, file.stem=output_filename_stem, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, format = "table", sep = ",")
```